# Firebase Timestamp showing the date of 1970

Tags: javascript, datetime, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get the current date and time from the firebase. Applying the following code while console logged I got the date of 1970. How to get the current date and time?

**Edited Code after getting solution**

```
let current_date;
firebase.database().ref("/.info/serverTimeOffset").on('value', function(offset) {
  current_date = new Date(Date.now() + offset.val());
  current_date.toString();            
});
console.log(current_date);
```

Comment: you might have a `unix timestamp`, so, try this: `new Date( offset.val() * 1000 )`

Comment: It's giving this as output - "Tue Jun 24 1975 09:04:23 GMT+0530 (IST)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below line

```
Date.now() + offset.val()
```

Then the code look like below

```
firebase.database().ref("/.info/serverTimeOffset").on('value', function(offset) {
 var date = new Date(Date.now() + offset.val());
 console.log(date.toString());  
});
```

Comment: so how to get the current date and time?

Comment: multiplying by 1000 gives me Tue Jun 24 1975 09:04:59 GMT+0530 (IST)

Comment: @Subhojit try this

Comment: showing error "TypeError: Date.now is not a constructor"

Comment: It's output shows just the timestamp! - "1506424667550"

Answer (score 1):

offset.val() does not give the current UNIX epoch. It tells you how many milliseconds the client's clock is from the Firebase server clock. In most cases this will be very small (~100ms), hence your issue.

To get current date:

```
firebase.database().ref("/.info/serverTimeOffset").on('value', function(offset) {
 var date = Date.now() + offset.val();
 console.log(date);  
});
```

Comment: showing error "TypeError: Date.now is not a constructor"

Comment: @Subhojit try without the `new` keyword.

Comment: @Subhojit yes, that’s the number of milliseconds since 1970 - the unix epoch